# \graphicspath{{}} can't reach in .rar file

Tags: graphics

I can't source images from .rar file for my paper. I tried specifying the directly by \graphicspath{{./sourcefile.rar/thefile.dir/}}, but it didn't work out.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Do you mean `sourcefile.rar` is a _file_ rather than a _directory_? If so, this can't work: you need the graphics files 'available'.

Comment: Yes, sourcfile.rar is an archive file that contains the directory for the images.

Comment: Welcome. // So, why not unpacking/unraring the file?

Comment: it is restricted.

Comment: TeX has no `rar` support build in. The only way to access these files will be unpacking the archive.

Comment: On Linux you can mount a rar file as a filesystem using rar2fs if you want, to make the file accessible for LaTeX without extracting first. But I'm not sure what you mean with the file being 'restricted'? If you can't extract it yourself due to path permissions or a password or something then LaTeX (or any other program that you can use) will also not be able to use the file in any way, conversely if you do have permission to read the file then you can extract it before use.